# To maintain the time relation between 2 actions, is it necessary to backshift the first verb

Tags: reported-speech

No,  I received his last email about 12 days ago.  He said that **he had not forgotten** me  and **was trying** to find some other stuff.

the second sentence is reported speech:the direct speech was
"I did not forget you and I am trying to find some stuff "

Do you think the tenses are well chosen?
I am not sure for the first one; may be to backshift was not necessary because at the time of reporting it was still true . But the first action of not forgetting began a long time before before the trying so, it is better to maintain the time relation between these 2 actions and  to choose past perfect

Comment: That's fine. It suggests that he is still looking. If he had disappeared or been killed in the interim, you might say **had been trying to find**... but this is most unlikely.

Comment: [choose, chose, chosen=verb; choice=a noun//maybe backshif**ing** etc..]

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think the tenses have been properly chosen?

Yes. It does look correct. This is a good application of  past perfect.